# Could anyone help me to solve the following differential equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, greens-function

I have a problem with the solution of this PDE, how can I start to solve it?

$
\left(\partial_x^2 
+
\frac{1}{x}\partial_x 
+
\partial_y^2 \right) F(x,y) =  
\frac{4\pi I}{x} \left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2+(y\pm M)^2}-2M}
{\sqrt{x^2+(y\pm M)^2}+2M}\right)^{1/2}\delta(x-x_0)\delta(y-y_0) 
$

where $I$ and $M$ are the positive constants.

Comment: What are the boundary conditions? What is the origin of this equation (what is the physical or some other problem which leads to this PDE)? What kind of solution do you expect (this should be known before attempting to solve PDEs)

Comment: This equation came out when I calculate the magnetic field of current loop in curved space. In flat space, the answer is elliptic function E(k) and K(k) form. It will be perfect If I find Green's function for this equation (operator).

Comment: If we set M=0 then we can easily have Coulomb-type Green's function.